# Big React Class or external controller?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a React class which have over 200 lines of code. Currently the class looks something like this:

```
export default class MyClass extends Component {
  method_1() {
    // Do stuff
    // Do  more stuff
    //...
  }
  method_n() {
    // Do stuff
    // Do  more stuff
    //...
  }
}
```

My question is that is it a good practice to use external controller that does all or most of the work inside those methods? It would look something like this:

```
const myController = new Controller();

export default class MyClass extends Component {
  method_1() {
    myController.doAllTheStuff();
  }
  method_n() {
    myController.doAllTheStuff();
  }
}
```

This would make the Class a lot smaller and more readable. But is it worth it because you still need to look inside the controller to see what is going on?

Comment: 200 lines isn't much. I would leave it there unless it's better off in the business logic area (e.g. redux thunk or saga), or could be a pure reusable function (in a utility file). I personally don't like the concept of controllers and it's a paradigm not used in React much (more Angular)

Answer (score 1):

It is worth it, because it will be easier to understand what is going on inside your class.

And if you add a comment before any call to a helper function then it will not be always needed to look into the helper function's code, since it will be clear from these comments what these functions do.